# Using data from a ViewModel in a ModalDialog even though it lives in the Shell

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, template10

I'm writing a UWP and using Template 10.

I've created a ModalDialog that should show the user some data that was just calculated in a ViewModel.

Here's where I'm lost:

> **#1, the ModalDialog needs data from my ViewModel. #2, the ModalDialog needs to call 1+ method(s) on the ViewModel depending on which button the user clicks.**

My Shell.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class Shell : Page
{
    public static Shell Instance { get; set; }
    public static HamburgerMenu HamburgerMenu => Instance.MyHamburgerMenu;


    public Shell()
    {
        Instance = this;
        InitializeComponent();
        if (App.MobileService.CurrentUser == null)
            LoginModal.IsModal = true;
    }

    public Shell(INavigationService navigationService) : this()
    {
        SetNavigationService(navigationService);
    }

    public void SetNavigationService(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        MyHamburgerMenu.NavigationService = navigationService;
    }

    #region Login

    private void LoginLoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       MyHamburgerMenu.NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.MainPage));
       LoginModal.IsModal = false;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Shell.xaml

```
<Controls:ModalDialog x:Name="ScoreModal" Grid.RowSpan="3"
                          CanBackButtonDismiss="False"
                          DisableBackButtonWhenModal="True">
        <Controls:ModalDialog.ModalContent>
            <myControls:QuizScorePart
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </Controls:ModalDialog.ModalContent>
    </Controls:ModalDialog>
```

### What I've tried:

I tried just putting the control for the ModalDialog in the View that uses the ViewwModel I wish to speak to, but that doesn't work; that view lives inside the shell, meaning everything underneath the ModalDialog is NOT disabled. It HAS to be in the Shell, from what I know.

I tried setting up a method in the Shell.xaml.cs file that sets IsModal for my dialog to true/false; this works, but it doesn't solve my problem of interacting with my ViewModel.

I'm lost. Thanks anyone for the help.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: It's strange that you have a public constructor and a singleton `Instance` property.

Comment: Everything except the login stuff is how it was set up with the template when I created the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reference the Search example, there are delegates to handle in the actual part, look at the codebehind for the LoginPart....

What I specified below in comments is how I do it with a LoginPage, not a usercontrol.  Which has a LoginPageViewModel which in-turn has a the SettingsService instance referenced.

#### Edit

Think of it this way...ScoreModal isn't anything other than another view control.  QuizScorePart is your View, I assume that QuizScorePartViewModal exists. From there it becomes a message passing exercise between viewmodels.  At least that is what I see after the last comment.  You need to know what the user clicked on button wise.  Assuming that the above is true, then QuizViewModel would react to that message it was listening for.  Shell is merely a holding location for a complete screen cover for the it only reacts to IsModal.  If that is an issue consider a Service to hold the button selection, similar to how SettingsService works.  Nothing says that QuizScorePart couldn't have its datacontext set to that of the QuizViewModel, but it might be a testing issue at that point.

Comment: I've looked at it. It has events that "talk" to the Shell. But that doesn't answer how I can talk to my ViewModel. The control lives in the Shell, which is why I can talk to it with events.

Comment: I actually don't use that method to show a login... I do it through a full page and using the _settings.IsFullScreen = true, forcing the Hamburger to be completely out of sight.  This way the SettingsService handles what you are talking about.  IsFullScreen I think was part the updated Template10 project that was pushed out.

Comment: In regards to your ViewModel "which one", you don't really give us much of your puzzle.  LoginViewModel, ShellViewModel (if you created one)... etc... Specifically what are you trying to communicate to the viewmodel?

Comment: I didn't include the ViewModel. For the Shell, I just use the Code-Behind, which is what I've shown. I have a ViewModel named QuizViewModel -- When ShowScoreModal in QuizViewModel is true, I want the Modal to show-- but I need it to show data from QuizViewModel and have its' buttons bound to commands inside of QuizViewModel.

Comment: I have thought the Modal control was alittle backasswards for mvvm, it doesn't lend itself well..  There is viewservice coming soon that might alleviate some of the headache, it just hasn't been merged into the project yet.

Comment: Question: "nothing says QuizScorePart" can't have its Data Context set to that of QuizViewModel" -- this would be if I didn't use the Service method, right? I tried that but it creates its' own object of QuizViewModel instead of using the one I'm using for QuizPage. So unless there's a different way to set it to use that specific object of QuizViewModel, this way wouldn't work. Thank you for the service suggestion, I wil look into it.

Comment: Also, I'm using PRISM. I think EventAggragators might work too, according to this blog? Thanks for the help. https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/communication-between-viewmodels-with-mvvm/